FTP inbound Adaptor send file to remote after SQS message send
I am implementing an @InboundChannelAdapter scenario where I need to move file to remote archive directory after sending message to AWS SQS queue. I have successfully achieved similar scenario with database using TransactionSynchronizationFactory and ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor setting setAfterCommitExpression.
My Sqs service activator
  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sqsRequisitionToAlmSendChannel")
  public MessageHandler sqsMessageHandler(@Autowired SqsAsyncClient amazonSqs) {
    SqsMessageHandler sqsMessageHandler = new SqsMessageHandler(amazonSqs);
    sqsMessageHandler.setQueueNotFoundStrategy(QueueNotFoundStrategy.FAIL);
    sqsMessageHandler.setQueue(queue_name);
    return sqsMessageHandler;
  }


Usually I recommend to use PublishSubscribeChannel, where the second subscriber would do the required stuff for the same message only if the first one is successful.
See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/channel/implementations.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel.
You also can look into ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice with its successChannel option to be provided into that @ServiceActivator endpoint.
Also see docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/handler-advice/classes.html#expression-advice
